# Workflow to upgrade a Flutter project/application

Tags: flutter

I have several Flutter projects that I have been working with for some time. Some a rather new and others are older. I constantly upgrade my Flutter SDK and switch between stable and beta channels. Everything works but the newer projects have different file layouts, for example `.gitignore` in android/ios folders, new XCode config files etc.

How do I update an older project to the new layout so as if it was just generated with `flutter create`?

Also there is this `.metadata` file generated which makes no sense to me. It never gets updated and only has it's `project_type` read by `flutter_tools` during `flutter create`. What is this for, why is it not being updated to the correct channel/rev?

Due to my research for the former question, I have run `flutter create .` in an existing project which generates some new files. Is this the only way, together with manually diffing to a new pristine project? And why is the `.metadata` file still outdated?

If anyone has some insights or documentation links regarding this, that would be great. I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Apparently one can update the initially generated Flutter configuration files by re-running `flutter create .`.

**Old:**

Somewhat answering my own question here.

On March 3rd a commit was added to Flutter that added the notion of migrations to the iOS template/configuration (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/e491544588e8d34fdf31d5f840b4649850ef167a).
These migrations take care of bringing the XCode configuration files to the latest version.
This commit has been ported back until Flutter 1.15.x.

This a great step forward. Hopefully similar migrations will be added for Android configurations and basic project files in the future.